# Return values does not work in printf() formatting

Tags: c, printf

The problem here is when I try to print the result as in the following code, this will give an output as "0 is the result."; however, when I assign pow(5,3) to a variable x then write printf("%d is the result.\n",x); it prints the correct result. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int power(int base, int exp) {
        int result = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < exp; i++) {
            result *= base;
        }
        return result;
    }

    int main() {

        printf("%d is the result.\n", power(5,3));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: With your edit the function is named `power`, but then you are calling `pow`.

Comment: can't reproduce http://ideone.com/ZqpaNv

Comment: This question has no sense now. Should we flag it?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem was because of my CodeBlocks so when I compiled and run it in terminal, it worked correctly so you can flag it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me when I try your program. But `pow` is a library function from the math library, returning double, and the name is reserved. Try to rename it to something like `my_pow`.